# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::fromToday()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I get this error when using this command: $todaysLog:
`$user->Logs()->fromToday()->get();`

User Model:

```
    public function Logs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Log::class);
    }
```

Log Model:

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function fromToday()
    {
        return $this->whereDate('day', Carbon::today());
    }
```

Comment: It seems you've forgotten to mention the error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare it as a scope to use it in the query builder

Log Model

```
public function scopeFromToday($query)
{
    return $query->whereDate('day', Carbon::today());
}
```

With the same syntax

```
$user->Logs()->fromToday()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use scope on `Log` model:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

//...

    /**
     * @param Builder $builder
     * @return Builder
     */
    public function scopeFromToday(Builder $builder): Builder
    {
        return $builder->whereDate('day', today());
    }
```

It can be called the same way:

```php
$user->Logs()->fromToday()->get();
```